# Setting specific colors transparent in XYZ-Tile-Layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, transparency-opacity, xyz

I need to set one (several) color(s) in an XYZ-Layer to "transparent" in QGIS.

When using a "Raster Layer" in QGIS I'm able to define specific colors as transparent via  "Layer Properties" >> "Transparency".

When I try to use the same features with an XYZ-Layer, these fields are disabled.

How do I solve that using QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

It's a pity, that in QGIS this is not possible directly.
But if you install [MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org/), configure your XYZ-layer and call back the MapProxy layer as WMS source, you can apply the transparency via option  ***[image](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.13.1/sources.html#image)***:

```yaml
image:
  transparent_color: '#ffffff'
  transparent_color_tolerance: 20
```

Unfortunately, this workaround is needed because in Mapproxy it's even not possible to configure a transparent color for a TMS source. But you can do it for [WMS sources](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.13.1/sources.html#wms).

https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapproxy/2015-June/002130.html

Comment: Thanks Christoph for your solution. I will have that in mind as a fallback option. 
But I was wondering, if some scripting could do that workaround within QGIS, without the need of additional SW

Answer (score 1):

You could export your image as @Babel has mentioned, but better create a GDAL_WMS description file for your XYZ-Layer (i.e. *frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml*):

```xml
<GDAL_WMS>
    <Service name="TMS">
        <ServerUrl>https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl>
    </Service>
    <DataWindow>
        <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
        <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
        <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
        <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
        <TileLevel>18</TileLevel>
        <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
        <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
        <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
    </DataWindow>
    <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
    <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
    <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
    <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
    <Cache />
</GDAL_WMS>
```

Load the file via drag&drop into QGIS and set your transparent pixels as needed.
[image]

[image]

P.S. if your image won't show in QGIS, you have to set the environment variable *GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL* to *YES*.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can download the image as a raster file: `right click layer > Export > Save as....` Set Extent and Resolution.
2. Then you can load the saved raster file and apply transparency as usual - see screenshot:

[image]